# 2 look up tables depending on variable date in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to get a cell to look up data from 2 tables depending on a date, eg if before June 30 2012 look up table A and if after 1 July 2012 look up table B

I have put in the following calculation to no avail

`=IF(G49<AH175,,VLOOKUP(Y49,$AI$178:$AU$181,AK$176,0)),IF(G49>AH214,,VLOOKUP(Y49,$AI$217:$AU$220,AK$176,0))`

- so Y49 is the cell
- AH175 is the date 31/7/2012
- AH214 is the date 1/7/2012
- $AI$178:$AU$181,AK$176 is table A
  -$AI$217:$AU$220,AK$176 is Table B
  can some one tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

The `VLOOKUP` function format is

> VLOOKUP(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])

You can put an `IF` around the `table_array` parameter to choose different ranges based on a condition

Something like this (assuming you want to return from the column number specified in `AK$176`)

```
=VLOOKUP(Y49,IF(Y49<AH214,$AI$178:$AU$181,$AI$217:$AU$220),AK$176,0)
```

Comment: That helped heaps thank you, now how do I write the formula to get a return from either column AK176 Table A or AK213 Table B?